# Copying and editing a text file on server, and allowing a temporarily download with PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to be able to copy a text file that's on my server, edit it based on the user input, and allow them to download the new file, but then delete it either after their session is done, or a certain amount of time.

I know how to copy and edit files, but I don't know how to make temporary files or a temporary directory, or how to dynamically name them... If multiple people are making files at once, I don't want to run into problems with making two files of the same name.

I've tried searching, but I'm not exactly sure how to phrase it. I've come across some pages on the PHP site about temporary files that are deleted as soon as the PHP stops running, but that wouldn't allow the users to download the file.

What exactly I would like to know:

-How to dynamically name copies of server files that are automatically deleted after a certain amount of time.

edit: Sorry, I know this might be more of a website problem than PHP, but I'm new to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tempnam()` to create a unique filename:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

There is also `tmpfile()`, which does the same, except that it a) Also creates the file and returns a file handle instead of a filename and b) automaticlly deletes the file at `fclose()` or when the script ends.

If you want to copy a file, then `tempnam()` would probably be the best suited.

You can delete the files manually at the end of the script, or just use a cronjob to delete them if there more than a day old. If you can't set cronjobs, you can create a "adminpage" and fetch it every day orso using a cronjob (Or scheduled task) from another machine.

**To answer the question "How do I delete old files":**

First, you will probably want to set the `$prefix` argument for `tempnam()` to a "separate" directory. By default, it'll typically use `/tmp/` which holds lots of other stuff. Use `/tmp/mydir/` (Make sure to check if it exists before writing to it!) or something in your home directory.

After that, you have two methods to find and clean up the files.

The first is using `find`, this is a powerful commandline tool which, as you might of guessed, finds files. As command fill in:

```
find /tmp/mydir/ -type f -and -mtime -1d -delete
```

To briefly explain: `-type f` means it only matches files (and not directories), `-mtime -1d` means it only matches files with a modification date of minus 1 day ago. And finally `-delete` will delete the file.

`find` is very powerful and useful, but may also be a bit daunting.

Another method is writing your own (PHP) script to search for files and call that. You can use `scandir()` to get a list of a directory contents, and `stat()` to get various info about files (Such as modification date).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer. So, `tempnam()` creates a new file with a temporary name. Is there any way to do this with copying a file? If I write the contents of the file I want to copy to the temp file, would that be just about the same thing?

Comment: Ohhh, I think I see what you mean now. I can just use that filename to copy the file with and I don't have to actually use the temporary file created. Also, what's a cronjob? I'm googling it now too...

Comment: ^ Yes. ``tempnam()`` will just create a filename for you, you can then copy to this filename. A cronjob is like a scheduled task in Windows, meaning it will execute a task every X minutes/hours/days automatically. It's UNIX/Linux talk, sorry :) When you've been using UNIX at much as I have it kind of becomes a second nature.

Comment: Yeah, I bet. Turns out 000webhost has an easy little page for adding cronjobs. I'm not familiar with unix or linux, so this is all pretty foreign to me. I want it to check every hour and delete files that are older than one hour... Do you know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Not gone, just making coffee :-) A programmer is a person who converts caffeine into code :-) I updated my answer.

Comment: Ha, thanks man. I really appreciate the help. I was looking here: http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/, and it said I could run PHP with cronjobs. I at least have some experience in PHP, so I would feel safer with deleting files and whatnot.

So I could just create a php script that iterates through each file in a directory and deletes it if it's older than 1 hour right? What would be the best way to do it like that? 

If not, I could just do `find /tmp/mydir/ -type f -and -mtime -1h -delete`, right?